# How do I download a english version

Tags: system-language

When I download Ubuntu to make a bootable USB, I get only a Chinese UBUNTU. How do I download a English version

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

Well you maybe downloaded the chinese version , go to this link for downloading the universal version :

[Ubuntu.com/download/desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)